# Cursor dissappears when set to high resolution in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, display-resolution, cursor, xorg.conf

I had a problem with the cursor . Currently installed Ubuntu 14.04, kernel driver `i915`. When i set the resolution `1920x1080` screen , the cursor disappears. At lower resolutions , the cursor is displayed .

Tried to

- reinstall the operating system
- change the refresh rate of the monitor frame
- update cursors in prescribed `xorg.conf` `Option "HWCursor" "off"` and `Option "SWCursor" "on"`
- updated driver package

Nothing helped. Any idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is solved** . There was a problem in the updates after you install the update at a high resolution cursor disappeared if they are not installed , then the resolution of 1920x1080 cursor visible.

Comment: I have the same problem... but I can't understand what you're trying to say in this answer...?